# How to understand stock return comovement

Tags: portfolio, factor-models, asset-pricing

In his book "Asset Pricing" chapter 20, Cochrane said

> For example, suppose that average returns were higher for stocks
>   whose ticker symbols start later in the alphabet. (Maybe investors
>   search for stocks alphabetically, so the later stocks are “over-
>   looked.”) This need not trouble us if Z stocks happened to have higher
>   betas. If not – if letter of the alphabet were a CAPM anomaly like
>   book to market – however, it would not necessar- ily follow that
>   letter based stock portfolios move together. Adding A-L and M-Z
>   portfolios to the right hand side of a regression of the 26 A,B,C,
>   etc. portfolios on the market portfolio need not (and probably does
>   not) increase the R 2 at all.

I am having trouble understanding this example. He is trying to illustrate why forming HML and SMB the way Fama and French did to explain the 25 Size/Book to Market Portfolio is not tautology.

Comment: He is saying these are 2 very different things: (1) a group of stocks have higher returns than another group of stocks, (2) a group of stocks move together. You can have one without the other.